# Sourcing or creating (using PHP), a lists of all countries and their relevant ISO codes?

Tags: county

I'm hoping that someone could help me find a complete list of all countries and their relevant ISO codes. More precisely, what I'm looking for is:

```
ISO 4217, ISO 3166-1, ISO 639-1, country name
```

Example:

```
EUR, IE, en, Ireland
```

Everything I find seems to be in bit's and pieces. I could spend a lot of time fixing it all together but I was hoping that someone would know; either a way to programmatically create the list through PHP or know of a place where this has already been done?

Most relevant sources already visited:

```
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217][1]
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1][2]
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1][3]
[http://www.fincher.org/Utilities/CountryLanguageList.shtml][4]
[https://gist.github.com/vxnick/380904][5]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- http://peric.github.io/GetCountries/ seems to have everything you want except the language code however it is in SQL format which could be fairly easily converted.
- http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ISOcodes/ISOcodes.pdf also seems to have all  your data but is in R format

Answer (score 2):

ISO stopped making ISO 3166-1 codes freely available from their website as of Feb. 20, 2014. For the convenience of others I stored an archived version of the last FREE versions at:

http://www.opengeocode.org/archive.php

The CIA World Factbook field listing 2098 lists the official languages per country. The link is:

https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2098.html

I have a version I converted to CSV that can be found at:

http://www.opengeocode.org/cude1.1/CIA/WFB/2098.zip

Parent link is: http://www.opengeocode.org/cude1.1/CIA/WFB/

fyi> I am a co-founder of OpenGeoCode.org

Answer (score 2):

I've added all (249) iso country codes as comma-separated values (CSV) files on github. See [countries(249)_alpha2.csv](https://github.com/openmundi/world.csv/blob/master/countries%28249%29_alpha2.csv), [countries(249)_alpha3.csv](https://github.com/openmundi/world.csv/blob/master/countries%28249%29_alpha3.csv) and [countries(249)_num3.csv](https://github.com/openmundi/world.csv/blob/master/countries%28249%29_num3.csv), files for example. Cheers.

fyi> I am the open mundi project lead.